# Google Graphs API / Some sort of Graph API

Tags: php, graph

I have been looking for days but could not figure it out. The biggest requirement is to have the image processed on the server and I can embed the url.

I have two datasets that I want to plot on the graph. I would like to use dataset 1 as a line graph, then dataset 2 as a bar graph.

I've used the chart wizard(https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard) to take a base image to insert dataset 1 and 2. However dataset 2 is also a line graph instead of the desired bar graph.

Here is an example of the two datasets:
[image]

I am open to using a different api or script that can do so.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why can't this be generated on the client? With something like http://www.jqplot.com/?

Comment: Reason being is I'm trying to insert it into an xml file.

Comment: @rcdmk inserting a url into the xml that another program can pull the url and embed it on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to solve my problem was to use pcharts. I would generate a url with the pcharts on the server side and embed url as an image. It looked like it worked. Google's API required js to execute to complete a combo chart where as pcharts did not.